# How can I fix these errors that occured while initializing a new Angular project?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

i updated my question please help me
[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Top4.png)

Comment: delete `node_modules` folder and try `npm install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open the `package.json` file and change jasmine-core" `3.7.1` to `3.8` and "karma-jasmine-html-reporter" from `1.5.0` to `1.7.0` and save it in devDependancies

Then run

```
npm install
ng serve
```

Comment: No i have no node_module folder

Comment: @Dmitrii I have update my answer. try it.

Comment: No I'm so sorry but it didn't help. I updated my question

Comment: @Dmitrii try to rebuild using `npm install`

Comment: I found where was trouble in. The current Angular version requires an active LTS or maintenance LTS version of Node.js. But I had the 16th version of Node.js, which doesn't maintain it. So I removed it and downloaded the 14th version of Node.js. S M A R T

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a node module folder, you have to run

```
npm install
```

command first.

If you already have node module file, you can delete the folder and then run **npm install** command.

If any of this does not work, you can delete the whole project folder and start from **`ng new`**.

If the issue continues, you can update the angular cli and core. Can you send a screenshot of the command prompt after running this command -  **`ng --version`**  ?